# Filter Rally defect on Last Updated Date

Tags: .net, filter, rally, defects

I am using the below code to retrieve the Defect data from rally. Currently, the defect is being filtered by Formatted ID.

Is there any way through i can filter the result by last updated date?

eg: **string queryString = @"(LastUpdateDate < 4\5\2013)";**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

{

RallyServiceService service = new RallyServiceService();

string rallyUser = "username";

string rallyPassword = "password";

`service.Url = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.41/RallyService";

         System.Net.NetworkCredential credential =
           new System.Net.NetworkCredential(rallyUser, rallyPassword);

        Uri uri = new Uri(service.Url);
        System.Net.ICredentials credentials = credential.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
        service.Credentials = credentials;
        service.PreAuthenticate = true;

         service.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

         // Find Defect
        //string queryString = @"(LastUpdateDate < 4\5\2013)";
String queryString = "(FormattedID = DE577)";

        // Order by FormattedID Ascending
        string orderString = "FormattedID asc";

        bool fetchFullObjects = true;

        // Paging information
        long start = 0;
        long pageSize = 200;

        // issue query
        QueryResult queryResult = service.query(null, "Defect", queryString, orderString, fetchFullObjects, 1, 20);

        // look at the object returned from query()
        Console.WriteLine("Query returned " + queryResult.TotalResultCount + " objects");

        Console.WriteLine("There are " + queryResult.Results.Length + " objects on this page");
        for (int i = 0; i < queryResult.Results.Length; i++)
        {
             DomainObject rallyobject = queryResult.Results[i];

            Defect defect = (Defect) rallyobject;
            Console.WriteLine("Date: "+defect.LastUpdateDate);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rally requires ISO8601-formatted Dates, so a query string of the format:

`string queryString = "(LastUpdateDate < \"2013-04-15\")";`

Should work for you.

Just a heads-up, especially if you're just getting started with building your integration, I'd highly recommend using one of Rally's [.NET REST SDK](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/rest-api-net) instead of SOAP.

REST is more robust, more performant, and, Webservices API 1.4x (x is yet-to-be-determined) will be the final API release to have SOAP support. Webservices 2.x will be REST-only, so using REST will be essential to anyone wanting new Webservices features moving forward.